# C++ std::string::find always returns npos?

Tags: c++, string, find

I'm trying to get this function to cut up a string, and then return it without whitespace and all lowercase. And to do this I'm trying to find a `" "` to see if a string, `"The Time Traveller (for so it will be convenient to speak of him)"`, contains a space.

The code is as follows, passing in the string above to this function. It always returns `string::npos`. Any idea about the problem?

```
string chopstring(string tocut){
    string totoken = ""; 
    int start = 0;
    while(tocut[0] == ' ' || tocut[0] == 10 || tocut[0 == 13]){
        tocut.erase(0);
    }
    int finish = 0;
    finish = tocut.find(" ", start);
    if (finish == string::npos){
        cout << "NPOS!" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = start; i < finish; i++){
        totoken += tocut[i];
    }
    tocut.erase(start, finish);
    return tokenize(totoken);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tocut.erase(0)` is erasing *all* of `tocut`. The argument is the *first* character to erase, and the default length is "everything".

`tocut[0 == 13]` should probably be `tocut[0] == 13`. Those are very different statements. Also, please compare with character values (`'\t'`) instead of integers. Incidentally, this in conjunction with the previous is your actual problem: `tocut[0 == 13]` becomes `tocut[false]`, which is `tocut[0]`, which is `true`. So the loop runs until `tocut` is empty, which is immediately (since you erase it all overzealously in the first go).

The net effect of the above two bugs is that when you reach the `find` statement, `tocut` is the empty string, which does not contain a space character. Moving on...

You can use the `substr` function instead of your loop to migrate from `tocut` to `totoken`.

Your last `tocut.erase(start, finish)` line isn't doing anything useful, since `tocut` was pass-by-value and you immediately return after that.

Comment: but on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/
it says 
iterator erase ( iterator position );
Erases the character referred by the iterator position. Only one character is affected.

Comment: Also, `tocut[0] == 10 || tocut[0 == 13]` look very odd.  If you want to compare vs character literals, use the actual literal (ie 10 instead of '`\n`'), it's far more readabe.  `tocut[0 == 13]` is presumably a typo, and since `0 == 13` is always false you'll return the value of the first character (which will be non-zero if the string isn't empty).  Again, use the character literal instead (`'\r'`)

Comment: @Samuraisoulification: `int` is not the same type as `string::iterator`.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification but you're passing an int, not an iterator, and so this overload `erase ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos );`  is being used instead.

Comment: @therefromhere and therefore it's erasing the whole thing? If I want it to be an iterator not and int, what should I do? also tocut[0 == 13] should be tocut[0] == 13. Typo.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification then you should use a `string::iterator` - `tocut.begin()` in this case.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification: Also, you shouldn't be converting `size_t` to `int`, it can lead to undefined behavior. Use `size_t`, or better yet, use `std::string::size_type`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the majority of the code could be written much simpler (assuming my understanding that you want to remove all spaces is correct):

```
string chopstring(string tocut) {
    std::string::size_type first(tocut.find_first_of(" \n\r"));
    if (first != tocut.npos) {
        tocut.substr(first);
    }
    tocut.erase(std::remove(tocut.begin(), tocut.end(), ' '), tocut.end());
    return tokenize(tocut);
}
```

If you actually want to remove all whitespace, you probably want to use `std::remove_if()` with a suitable predicate.